# Query executes in MySQL prompt but not in app

Tags: java, mysql

the following query executes correctly in MySQL prompt but got an error with Java 
(You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by (select avg( case grade when 'A+' then 4 when 'A' then 4 when 'A-' then 3.7 w' at line 1)

```
java.sql.ResultSet rslt= stmt.executeQuery("select name from student natural join takes t1 where (dept_name='Comp. Sci.')" +
        "group by ID" +
        "order by (select avg( case grade " +
                        "when 'A+' then 4 " +
                        "when 'A' then 4 " +
                        "when 'A-' then 3.7 " +
                        "when 'B+' then 3.5 " +
                        "when 'B' then 3 " +
                        "when 'B-' then 2.7 " +
                        "when 'C+' then 2.5 " +
                        "when 'C' then 2 " +
                        "when 'C-' then 1 " +
                        "end) as avg_gpa " +
                   "from takes t2 " +
               "where t1.ID=t2.ID) " +
        "limit 10");
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I dont think thats your java code. how do you connect the strings in each line?

Comment: I omitted the "" in each line just to simplify the code here (not in java)..
and I did not understand what you meant by not my java code?

Comment: please show that part too and I will show you the problem...

Comment: just copied and pasted the statement as it is from java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont forget the spaces after each line:

```
java.sql.ResultSet rslt= stmt.executeQuery(
"select name from student natural join takes t1 where (dept_name='Comp. Sci.') "+
"group by ID "+
"order by (select avg( case grade "+
        "when 'A+' then 4  "+
    "when 'A' then 4 "+
    "when 'A-' then 3.7 "+
    "when 'B+' then 3.5 "+
    "when 'B' then 3 "+
    "when 'B-' then 2.7 "+
    "when 'C+' then 2.5 "+
    "when 'C' then 2 "+
    "when 'C-' then 1 "+
    "end) as avg_gpa "+
    "from takes t2 "+
"where t1.ID=t2.ID) "+
"limit 10");
```

in your sql that is wrong:

```
"group by ID" +
        "order by (select avg( case grade " +
```

here you have a String like this: `"group by IDorder by (select avg( case grade"`

you see the problem?

add a space after `ID`

Comment: no prob :) feel free to click on the white hook top/left of my answer to accept.